# Nao estou conseguindo fazer com que as DIVs "coluna" fiquem uma ao lado da outra

Tags: html, css

Era para ficar 3 colunas uma ao lado da outra

```
         <div class="container"> 
                <div class="containerint">
                    <p>Confira nosso trabalho</p>
                    <div class="linha">
                       <div class="coluna">
                           <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/9010.jpg">
                           <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/DSC_0176.jpg">
                           <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/DSC_3113.jpg">
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="linha">
                       <div class="coluna">
                          <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/2408  20x25.jpg">
                          <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/6601.jpg"> 
                          <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/DSC_0582.jpg">
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="linha">
                       <div class="coluna">
                           <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/DSC_8184.jpg">
                           <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/476.jpg">
                           <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/DSC_1686.jpg">
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


 .containerint {
    width: 1100px;
    max-width: 100%;
    
    margin: auto;
    color: black;
}

.linha {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 4px;
}
.coluna {
    flex: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
    padding: 0 4px;
}


.coluna img {
    margin-top: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
    .coluna {
        flex:100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Acontece que elas ficam em apenas uma coluna.

Answer (score 1):

**Seu `CSS` está certo o seu `HTML` é que está errado**, veja que vc separou cada coluna individualmente dentro de uma Linha, mas na verdade vc tinha que ter 3 colunas dentro da linha ai sem vc vai ter 3 colunas uma ao lado da outra!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.containerint {
  width: 1100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  color: black;
}

.linha {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.coluna {
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}


.coluna img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
  .coluna {
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="containerint">
    <p>Confira nosso trabalho</p>
    <div class="linha">
      <div class="coluna">
        <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/9010.jpg">
        <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/DSC_0176.jpg">
        <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/DSC_3113.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="coluna">
        <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/2408  20x25.jpg">
        <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/6601.jpg">
        <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/DSC_0582.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="coluna">
        <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/2408  20x25.jpg">
        <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/6601.jpg">
        <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/DSC_0582.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="linha">
      <div class="coluna">
        <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/2408  20x25.jpg">
        <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/6601.jpg">
        <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/DSC_0582.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="linha">
      <div class="coluna">
        <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/DSC_8184.jpg">
        <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/476.jpg">
        <img src="./assets/images/Fotos site/DSC_1686.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo ajuda. Abraço!

Comment: @gabrielpertile se resolver lembre-se de marcar a resposta como aceita clicando no ✔️ abaixo das setas ao lado da resposta, assim ela não fica em aberto mesmo com o problema já tendo sido resolvido  ;)